# Не подключает модуль (flask), что не так?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, сервер, flask

Не подключает, да и не видит файл help.py, хотя в __init__.py прописан, в чём ошибка ?

Исходники https://github.com/dlamichhane/Flask-blog/tree/master/flaskblog

Сама ошибка:

```
flaskblog  python runserver.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagabund/web/flaskblog/flaskblog/\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from helper import url_for_other_page
ImportError: No module named 'helper'
```

**UPD**: после исправления импорта:

```
python runserver.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagabund/web/github/Flask-blog/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 109, in <module>
    for module, items in all_by_module.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

**UPD2**: Но затем, после запуска питона 2.7 появилась другая ошибка:

```
python2.7 runserver.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagabund/web/github/Flask-blog/flaskblog/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 87, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.sqlalchemy
```

Comment: Попробуйте написать `from flaskblog.helper import url_for_other_page`

Comment: @Nexus Оу, помогло, спасибо, но теперь почему-то появилась другая ошибка (ошибка в самом посте, обновлена)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка появляется в модуле werkzeug. На официальном сайте проекта написано, что модуль поддерживается python3.3 - у вас был 3.4. Не знаю точно, в чем различие этих конкретных версий. Но я бы попробовал запустить под Python 3.3

Answer (score 0):

А вот из второй ошибки я делаю вывод, что проект написан под другую версию питона. Возвращайте строку с `helper`'ом обратно, устанавливайте Python 2.7 и запускайте через Python 2.7.

Comment: Да, но теперь снова ещё одна ошибка, с подключаемым модулем flask.ext.sqlalchemy (пост обновлён), что же тепреь не так ? >.<
Вроде всё установил, и сам falsk-sqlalchemy и просто sqlalchemy

Comment: А вот это всё, наверно, надо заново установить для второго питона

Comment: «(пост обновлён)» — а вот так переписывать историю вообще нехорошо, с такими исправлениями вопрос становится бесполезен для других

Comment: Какая же команда будет для установки этих же модулей для второго питона ? (pip install 'модули' ? И что дальше, или что не так ?)

Comment: pip для второго питона, а не для третьего, разумеется. В Arch Linux это команда `pip2`, например

Comment: Спасибо!!! Помогло. Только с версиями питона и установкой pip2 пришлось немного заморочиться (удалить питон3 через sudo, затем переустановить virtualenv, точнее обновить).
А легко ли, и вообще просто переписать этот код под третью версию python`a ?